# .NET v2.0.50727 Loading Weird DLL

Tags: .net, exception

So, I've been working with C# for a while now and I got this error which is kind of weird.
The error refers to something that doens't exist.
I never referenced my project to any test.dll or whatever that is, only using a custom dll and the System ones.

The Error Log: http://tinypaste.com/cb350

Did not posted the log here because it kind of broke the layout?

Main:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        bool forceFirstRun = false;
        if (args.Length == 1)
            if (args[0].Trim().ToUpper() == "-ffr") // Force First Run
                forceFirstRun = true;

        if (forceFirstRun | args.Length == 0)
            Application.Run(new frmGUI());
        else
        {
            string[] cmdArgs = args;
            List<string> lstCmdArgs = new List<string>(cmdArgs);
            if (forceFirstRun)
            {
                lstCmdArgs.RemoveAt(0);
                cmdArgs = lstCmdArgs.ToArray();
            }
            ParseScript.Start(cmdArgs);
        }
    }
```

ParseScript class:
        class ParseScript
    {
        private static string ErrorMessage = "";

```
    private static string[] validVersionsArray = new string[] { "v171", "v1712 };
    private static List<string> validVersions = new List<string>(validVersionsArray);
```

...

The error happens right after defining List validVersion;

The ParseScript.Start is pretty big big but error happens right at the beginning while building the class on the Main method.

---

Sorry guys, problem was actually the fact that my debug parameters had a first working argument and it wasn't formatted properly, the path was using one backslash instead of two.

Comment: Can we see the code as well? Particularly Main and proj42.ParseScript.Start

Comment: Whats the custom dll? Does it reference (have a dependency on) test.dll?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was actually residing in the Debug Parameter.

The Command Line Arguments was using a unformatted path to a file, was using one backslash instead of two.

How this resulted in the load of this test.dll? I have no idea.

Much like I have no idea why 1 and 0 equals 1 and 0. lol

Answer (score 0):

Some source code and configuration files would help... assemblies can be loaded dynamically (for instance via configuration entries etc.), so that it is impossible to tell where the error originates without more information.

Comment: The error happens in this line: 
private static string[] validVersionsArray = new string[] { "v171", "v1712" };
private static List<string> validVersions = new List<string>(validVersionsArray);

this is in ParseScript.Start, the first lines, just some global variables.

Comment: Why I can't put new lines in the reply? How awkward.

Comment: And the custom dll I am loading have no reference to any test.dll

Comment: The code was working fine until last days, and only thing I did was to install ILMerger.

Comment: In that case, we'd need to see the entire ParseScript class. One of the members is triggering the bad reference. This could be in a return type, parameter type, or field type.

Comment: The ParseScript class is damn big, the error happen before even calling the method Start.

Comment: Could it be because I am calling a static method from just a random class? I tried to change the .NET from the application to v3.0 and it still gives me a error regarding v2.0

Comment: @user522617 - these are comments, not replies. They're not meant for code etc.